# how to install a package with gvm(Go Version Manager)? go get failed

Tags: go

I successfully installed `go1.6.2` with `gvm` and used `global` pkgset.
I am trying to install `gocode` package with gvm, but `go get` not working.
I guess gvm is not really stable yet?

```
➜  ~ gvm use 1.6.2
Now using version go1.6.2
➜  ~ gvm pkgset use global
Now using version go1.6.2@global
➜  ~  go get -u github.com/nsf/gocode
➜  ~ go list
can't load package: package .: no buildable Go source files in /Users/seoyoochan

➜  ~ go install gocode
can't load package: package gocode: cannot find package "gocode" in any of:
    /Users/seoyoochan/.gvm/gos/go1.6.2/src/gocode (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/seoyoochan/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.6.2/global/src/gocode (from $GOPATH)
    /Users/seoyoochan/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.6.2/global/src/gocode
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you `go get` some package, if it has buildable source, the `go install` commang will automatically run inside the package directory, so you don't need to `go install gocode`. just type `gocode` to check.

If you want to install it manually, you have to go to the directory first

```
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/nsf/gocode
go install
```

Also you cannot perform `go list` outside package directory

```
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/nsf/gocode
go list
```

Comment: I am quite not following because I am a noob in Go. so there's no easier way to install the package? As a Rubyist, I really love installing gems from RubyGems.org. If so, is my custom `pkgset` where I pull the source code and install it?

Comment: install package is so easy in golang, just `go install` is enough. but if you install package which come from `go get`, you won't automatically go to the package location. it's natural I think, you cannot install package without go to the location first.

Comment: `go get` will download package into `$GOPATH/src` folder. check on `$GOPATH` location. if you are using gvm, it'll saved to you `$pkgset/src`

Comment: I made up my mind to ditch gvm for now. gvm has too many issues to introduce in my workflow. :/ Thanks anyway!